# Extracting prefixed attributes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

For the below XML

```
<SampleXMLFormat>
  <Header>
    <Id>123</Id>
  </Header>
  <Properties>
    <property name="a1_prop1" value="val1"/>
    <property name="a1_prop2" value="val2"/>
    <property name="a2_prop1" value="val1"/>
    <property name="a2_prop2" value="val2"/>
    <property name="abcd" value="efgh"/>
  </Properties>
</SampleXMLFormat>
```

Can I please get the XSLT transformations for getting the following outputs:

1) Without properties with prefix `a2`

```
<SampleXMLFormat>
  <Header>
    <Id>123</Id>
  </Header>
  <Properties>
    <property name="a1_prop1" value="val1"/>
    <property name="a1_prop2" value="val2"/>
    <property name="abcd" value="efgh"/>
  </Properties>
</SampleXMLFormat>
```

2) Only properties with prefix `a2`

```
<property name="a2_prop1" value="val1"/>
<property name="a2_prop2" value="val2"/>
```

@ABach  For the 2nd part, im trying this..Instead of selecting all nodes,i am trying to select only property nodes ,but i get malformed output.Can you please advise what im doing wrong?

```
xslt = '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="property|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="property|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="property[not(starts-with(@name, \'BOND_\'))]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>';
```

Comment: Does "please can I get" mean "please write this for me"? That is not the purpose of Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER #1**

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="property[starts-with(@name, 'a2')]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied against the provided XML:**

```
<SampleXMLFormat>
  <Header>
    <Id>123</Id>
  </Header>
  <Properties>
    <property name="a1_prop1" value="val1"/>
    <property name="a1_prop2" value="val2"/>
    <property name="a2_prop1" value="val1"/>
    <property name="a2_prop2" value="val2"/>
    <property name="abcd" value="efgh"/>
  </Properties>
</SampleXMLFormat>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
<SampleXMLFormat>
  <Header>
    <Id>123</Id>
  </Header>
  <Properties>
    <property name="a1_prop1" value="val1"/>
    <property name="a1_prop2" value="val2"/>
    <property name="abcd" value="efgh"/>
  </Properties>
</SampleXMLFormat>
```

---

**ANSWER #2**

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="property[not(starts-with(@name, 'a2'))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied against the provided XML:**

```
<SampleXMLFormat>
  <Header>
    <Id>123</Id>
  </Header>
  <Properties>
    <property name="a1_prop1" value="val1"/>
    <property name="a1_prop2" value="val2"/>
    <property name="a2_prop1" value="val1"/>
    <property name="a2_prop2" value="val2"/>
    <property name="abcd" value="efgh"/>
  </Properties>
</SampleXMLFormat>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
<SampleXMLFormat>
  <Header>
    <Id>123</Id>
  </Header>
  <Properties>
    <property name="a2_prop1" value="val1"/>
    <property name="a2_prop2" value="val2"/>
  </Properties>
</SampleXMLFormat>
```

---

**EDIT:** the OP has added some clarity on the second question. In that case, this XSLT should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="*/property[starts-with(@name, 'a2')]" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: *Please* don't perpetuate the Novatchev style of **writing everything in bold**. It is painful to read.

Comment: @Borodin: you are the first person to have told me that. I will certainly do what I can, but not at the expense of outlining an answer vs. extra commentary. Thanks!

Comment: @ABach Thanks..Can u pls see what im doing wrong with the second part.The second part of your anser is not what i asked for.